# Can't resolve lighthouse warning "consider using link rel=preload"

Tags: performance, pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I get a error `consider using link rel=preload`

The file is "//fonts/themify.woff"

I added to the page head `<link rel="preload" href="//fonts/themify.woff" as="font" crossorigin="">` but still get the warning.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: care to share a link to the page, example looks fine.